# Dynamically Updating Image SRC using ES6

Tags: javascript, php, variables, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have global JavaScript variable that is defined in PHP for use in a WordPress Block.

When the page initially loads, the "stars" image appears as expected. When a change event is fired, a 404 error appears in the console with "https://site.dev/img/var_set_in_php.imageSunset" as the URL instead of "https://site.dev/img/sunset.jpg".

How can this be updated to pull in the value that is set in PHP? I'm new to ES6, so hoping it's just something simple that I'm missing.

```php
wp_localize_script(
    'image-js',
    'var_set_in_php', // Array containing dynamic data for a JS Global.
    array(
        'imageStars' => '/img/stars.jpg',
        'imageSunset' => '/img/sunset.jpg',
    )
);
```

```
function onChangeFunction(name) {
    // name is set to "Sunset"
    document.getElementById('image').src = `var_set_in_php.image${name}`;
}
```

```
<img src={var_set_in_php.imageStars} id="image" />
```

Comment: This is an X/Y problem - you need to fix the underlying issue instead of patching it with JS

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for your responses. I was just to just keep my example simple, but this is needed to update a preview image while working in the WordPress Editor. No, still getting that same error in the console. It's looking for an image with the variable name instead of trying to load it at the defined path.

Comment: `\`var_set_in_php.image${name}}\`` is also not healthy - there is a weird trailing `}`

Comment: The rendered HTML looks like: <img src="var_set_in_php.imageSunset" id="image">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a

```
var var_set_in_php = {
 'imageStars' :'/img/stars.jpg', 
 'imageSunset' : '/img/sunset.jpg'
}
```

and if you do, you need this to access the object with a compound variable

```
document.getElementById('image').src = var_set_in_php[`image${name}`];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Have been pulling my hair out over this! LOL Thank you!!

Comment: Almost made me pull it out too since I could not initially guess what the issue was without seeing the rendered JS (the rendered HTML did not help so I guessed)